# Using the discriminant to prove two graphs intersect at 2 points

Tags: calculus

I need help on my calculus homework for a question which asks to prove that the graphs of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ intersect at two points using the discriminant

I am given that $f(x)=x^3 - 3x^2$ and $h(x)=f(x+1)$

I found that $h(x)=(x+1)^3-3(x+1)^2$ so I let $a=(x+1)^2$ which would then give me $h(x)=a^2-3a$ and used the discriminant to find 2 solutions for $h(x)$. Now I am unsure of what to do from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve $f(x)=h(x)$ for $x$. If you write nicely you get the equivalent equation
$$3x^2-3x-2=0.$$
The solutions are
$$x=\frac{1}{6}\left(3\pm\sqrt{33}\right).$$